# How to find OS Architecture using batch with only numberic output?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

**I am running following command,**

```
@echo off
cls
wmic os get osarchitecture > win.txt
for /f "skip=1" %%G IN (win.txt) do echo %%G
pause>nul
```

**Actual output am getting is,**

```
Echo is off
```

**Expected output,**

```
64
```

*or*

```
32
```

*depends on user architecture..*

**in `win.txt` am getting output,**

```
OSArchitecture  
64-bit
```

*But in cmd window it shows blank `echo is off` donno why ! please fix my code. i need only 64 or 32 in output.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I need only 64 or 32 in output.

Use the following batch file (GetBits.cmd):

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem use findstr to strip blank lines
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=*" %%i in (`wmic OS get OSArchitecture ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do (
  set "_bits=%%i"
  rem extract first 2 characters
  set "_bits=!_bits:~0,2!"
  echo !_bits!
  )
endlocal
```

Example output:

```
F:\test>GetBits.cmd
64

F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [EnableDelayedExpansion - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [Findstr - Search for strings - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [For /f - Loop through text - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [variable substring - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a 1 liner that works:

```
IF EXIST %windir%\syswow64 ( ECHO 64 ) ELSE ( ECHO 32 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
@echo off
cls 
for "tokens=2 delims==- " %%a in ('wmic os get osarchitecture /format:value') do echo %%a 
pause >nul
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Error: `"tokens=2 delims=- " was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: I forgot to add an extra delims =